# Crashes/stucks of DAW programs on some VST plugins that use OpenGL on secondary display with Nvidia cards

Tags: opengl, vst

My particular problem is that Reaper DAW hangs/not responding when I try to open VST plugins on second and 3rd displays connected to my computer. They work normally if opened on 1st(main) display

The plugins affected: FabFilter, MeldaProduction, Waves

My system:
Win10,
Ryzen 3900x,
64Gb RAM,
NVME SSD,
1080Ti (3 displays connected), latest drivers

The problem with FabFilter can be solved as descripted here:
https://www.fabfilter.com/support/faq/#how-can-i-disable-graphics-acceleration-on-my-computer

The problem with MeldaProduction can be solved by disabling GPU acceleration in plugin settings.

However I found that it is general problem for many VST plugins and different DAWs: they hang or crash when Nvidia graphics card is used and more than 1 display is used.
I suppose it is OpenGL related problem, so maybe there is general solution for any VST plugin and any DAW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the general solution: Nahimic service causes the issue.

So disabling Nahimic service eliminates the problem and all plugins work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, if you can't switch off a plugin's reliance on OpenGL, I'm afraid is - get a better graphics card.

Many manufacturers cheap-skate OpenGL support to any non-primary display. You need to find one that doesn't.
This is not the fault of the NVidia chipset (or company) itself, but that of the actual card manufacturer.

I first discovered this whilst running online support for a gaming company. I honestly don't know how you discover which cards do support OpenGL properly on secondary displays, but that is definitely the cause & solution. On our game it would result in characters being simple black solids instead of fully rendered. Simply moving the game to the primary display would always fix it.
Interestingly, this seems to affect cards built for Window PCs far more than it does Macs. I have never found a Mac with this problem, only ever PCs.

I don't really use Melda or FabFilter much, but I've had Waves for over 15 years & never personally seen the issue (but I'm on a Mac).

Comment: It is strange, but I do not have any problem with running any game on any of my displays, I use Blender with multi-monitor layout, I use video editing software, I also can run FurMark on any of the displays. But I have this problem with VST plugins only.

Comment: Does everything else (apart from furmark) use OpenGL, or more commonly for Windows, DirectX? tbh, I don't have great experience with anything "graphicky" on Windows, other than the game support, which would be generally happy with OpenGL 2.1 minimum. A 1080, of course, should be good to 4.(something). This just turned out to always be the solution.

Comment: I am not sure about all software, but Blender definitely uses OpenGL https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/gpu/windows/nvidia.html

Answer (score 0):

This actually helped me, i was pulling hair ..

I have an ASUS Ryzen ROG STRIX Gaming MB and it has the Nahimic Service running. I am able to resolve the issue on either screen and reintroduce every time with enabling and disabling this service.

As with the opening post. Using Reaper , opening the Native Instruments Freak plugin froze Reaper instantly forcing a close of both plugin and DAW , tried installing latest Nvidia GFX drivers , no different, applying the Mesa3D.dll same , then saw this post regarding 2nd screen. Works fine launching from first Monitor, then moving around to second monitor, but launch the VST on the second monitor and it freezes again. Could be very disruptive in the middle of project.